# Getting error converting varchar to float when using "where [field] = 0"

Tags: sql-server, type-conversion

I work for a software company and convert clients' databases over from 3rd party software to ours. As such, my SQL knowledge is very niche, so I apologize if this is a silly question. I've tried to find something answering this but there seems to be a very wide variety of things that can cause this error, although I'm not necessarily proficient at searching for these types of questions.

**I'm trying to populate a table in our format and have about 6 tables joined (between source data an various mapping tables)**. I had my query running perfectly fine, and realized **I needed to break my records into two sweeps**, adding:

```
AND A.AP_PAID_AMT = 0
```

This was the only difference from my original query, and gave me the old

```
Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
Error converting data type varchar to float.
```

When I simply run

```
SELECT * FROM AP_ITEMS2 A WHERE A.AP_PAID_AMT = 0
```

I get results. `AP_PAID_AMT` is decimal(16,2).  I've tried a variety of things, such as adding `ISNULL(A.AP_PAID_AMT,0)`, converting and casting the value into various data types, etc.  And oddly enough if you make it <> 0 it works fine.

I can post the whole query if it would be helpful, but thought it might be more limited to data type and functions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: My guess is the parsing problem is in another field. Replace * with fields, one at a time and test it. Also, you can try `ISNUMERIC` function before casting

Comment: Tried that too.  If I comment that part of the where clause it works fine...and as mentioned I can select from that field where = 0 when it's just straight off it.  Thanks though.

Comment: I said the problem might not be in where but in selected values. Have you checked this? Suppose you have a field (column) with all numbers in every row except for a row where `A.AP_PAID_AMT = 0`

Comment: Are you using `SELECT *` or some functions applied to some columns?

Comment: Apologies, I wasn't clear.  I took out each value of my query one at a time and didn't have any success.  However, I found that in one of the joined tables there was some junk data in one of the columns I was joining on that didn't trip me up until I added that additional clause - some alpha characters that had no business being there (again, 3rd party db).  I'm still not sure why it gave me problems on a smaller subset of my original query, since I was only limiting it down further - but I do see it was a data type issue that I should have addressed earlier.  Thank you for your help!